# Transitioning d3.radar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to figure out how to add a transition onto Alangrafu's radar chart, so instead of refreshing the whole chart with new data it would just move the points.

Or if that is too complicated, perhaps an affect like the one offered with [Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/).

However, it is a lot more difficult than I initially thought it would be. (I'm a fairly low level programmer!)

I was hoping someone could offer any tips/insight on how to do this? (And if it is possible to do without a large rewrite of the original code?)

I thought it would be as easy as adding a transition where the area chart called (seen below), sadly I was wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8g8s6Lz/

I would be very grateful for any help!

Thanks

```
g.selectAll(".area")
                .data([dataValues])
                .enter()
                .transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .ease(cubic)
                .append("polygon")
                .attr("class", "radar-chart-series_"+series)
                .style("stroke-width", strokeWidthPolygon)
                .style("stroke", cfg.color(series))
                .attr("points",function(d) {
                    var str="";
                    for (var pti=0;pti<d.length;pti++) {
                        str=str+d[pti][0]+","+d[pti][1]+" ";
                    }
                    return str;
                })
                .style("fill", function(j, i) {
                    return cfg.color(series);
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a real quick hack for what you are after:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <style>
    .big.radarChart {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    #chart-radar1 {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="update">Update</button>
  <div class="big radarChart" id="chart-radar" ></div>
  <script>
    var wMaior = 400;
    var wMenor = 200;

    var colorscale = d3.scale.category10();
    var legendOptions = ['Legend 1'];
    var size = 2;

    if (size > 0) {
      var json = [
        [{
          "axis": "A",
          "value": 6
        }, {
          "axis": "B",
          "value": 4
        }, {
          "axis": "C",
          "value": 6
        }, {
          "axis": "D",
          "value": 5.5
        }, {
          "axis": "E",
          "value": 8
        }, {
          "axis": "F",
          "value": 7
        }, {
          "axis": "G",
          "value": 9
        }, {
          "axis": "H",
          "value": 10
        }, {
          "axis": "I",
          "value": 3.5
        }]
      ];
    }

    function drawRadarCharts() {
      drawRadarChart('#chart-radar', wMaior, wMaior);
    };

    function drawRadarChart(divId, w, h) {
      var textSizeLevels = "10px !important";
      var textSizeTooltip = "13px !important";
      var textSizeLegend = "11px !important";
      var circleSize = 5;
      var strokeWidthPolygon = "2px";

      var RadarChart = {
        draw: function(id, data, options) {
          var cfg = {
            radius: circleSize,
            w: w,
            h: h,
            factor: 1,
            factorLegend: .85,
            levels: 3,
            maxValue: 0,
            radians: 2 * Math.PI,
            opacityArea: 0.001,
            ToRight: 5,
            TranslateX: 80,
            TranslateY: 30,
            ExtraWidthX: 10,
            ExtraWidthY: 100,
            color: d3.scale.category10()
          };

          if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
            for (var i in options) {
              if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) {
                cfg[i] = options[i];
              }
            }
          }

          cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(data, function(i) {
            return d3.max(i.map(function(o) {
              return o.value;
            }));
          }));
          var allAxis = (data[0].map(function(i, j) {
            return i.axis;
          }));
          var total = allAxis.length;
          var radius = cfg.factor * Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2);
          
          var svg = d3.select(id).select('svg'),
              polyPoints = null;
          if (svg.node()){
             polyPoints = svg.select("polygon").attr("points");
             svg.remove(); 
          }

          var g = d3.select(id)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.ExtraWidthX)
            .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.ExtraWidthY)
            .attr("class", "graph-svg-component")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.TranslateX + "," + cfg.TranslateY + ")");

          var tooltip;

          // Circular segments
          for (var j = 0; j < cfg.levels - 1; j++) {
            var levelFactor = cfg.factor * radius * ((j + 1) / cfg.levels);
            g.selectAll(".levels")
              .data(allAxis)
              .enter()
              .append("svg:line")
              .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin((i + 1) * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos((i + 1) * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("class", "line")

            .style("stroke", "grey")
              .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
              .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w / 2 - levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h / 2 - levelFactor) + ")");
          }

          // Text indicating at what % each level is
          for (var j = 0; j < cfg.levels; j++) {
            var levelFactor = cfg.factor * radius * ((j + 1) / cfg.levels);
            g.selectAll(".levels")
              .data([1]) //dummy data
              .enter()
              .append("svg:text")
              .attr("x", function(d) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(0));
              })
              .attr("y", function(d) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(0));
              })
              .attr("class", "legend")
              .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .style("font-size", textSizeLevels)
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w / 2 - levelFactor + cfg.ToRight) + ", " + (cfg.h / 2 - levelFactor) + ")")
              .attr("fill", "#737373")
              .text((j + 1) * cfg.maxValue / cfg.levels);
          }

          series = 0;

          var axis = g.selectAll(".axis")
            .data(allAxis)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", axis);

          axis.append("line")
            .attr("x1", cfg.w / 2)
            .attr("y1", cfg.h / 2)
            .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
              return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
              return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .style("stroke-width", "1px");

          axis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d;
            })
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", textSizeLegend)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", "1.5em")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0, -10)";
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
              return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - cfg.factorLegend * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)) - 60 * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
              return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total)) - 20 * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total);
            });

          data.forEach(function(y, x) {
            dataValues = [];
            g.selectAll(".nodes")
              .data(y, function(j, i) {
                dataValues.push([
                  cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)),
                  cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total))
                ]);
              });
            dataValues.push(dataValues[0]);
            g.selectAll(".area")
              .data([dataValues])
              .enter()
              .append("polygon")
              .attr("points", function(d){
                if (polyPoints)
                  return polyPoints;
                else
                  return d3.range(d.length).map(function(){
                    return (cfg.w / 2) + "," + (cfg.h / 2)
                  }).join(" ");
              })
              .attr("class", "radar-chart-series_" + series)
              .style("stroke-width", strokeWidthPolygon)
              .style("stroke", cfg.color(series))
              .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
              .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                z = "polygon." + d3.select(this).attr("class");
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                g.selectAll(z)
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
              })
              .on('mouseout', function() {
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
              })
              .transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .attr("points", function(d) {
                var str = "";
                for (var pti = 0; pti < d.length; pti++) {
                  str = str + d[pti][0] + "," + d[pti][1] + " ";
                }
                return str;
              })
              .style("fill", function(j, i) {
                return cfg.color(series);
              })

            series++;
          });

          series = 0;

          data.forEach(function(y, x) {
            var c = g.selectAll(".nodes")
              .data(y).enter()
              .append("svg:circle")
              .attr("class", "radar-chart-series_" + series)
              .attr('r', cfg.radius)
              .attr("alt", function(j) {
                return Math.max(j.value, 0);
              })
              .attr("cx", function(j, i) {
                dataValues.push([
                  cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)),
                  cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total))
                ]);
                return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (Math.max(j.value, 0) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("cy", function(j, i) {
                return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (Math.max(j.value, 0) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
              })
              .attr("data-id", function(j) {
                return j.axis;
              })
              .style("fill", cfg.color(series))
              .style("fill-opacity", 0)
              .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;

                tooltip.attr('x', newX)
                  .attr('y', newY)
                  .text(d.value)
                  .transition(200)
                  .style('opacity', 1);

                z = "polygon." + d3.select(this).attr("class");
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                g.selectAll(z)
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
              })
              .on('mouseout', function() {
                tooltip.transition(200)
                  .style('opacity', 0);
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                  .transition(200)
                  .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
              });
              
            c.transition()
              .delay(1750)
              .duration(100)
              .style("fill-opacity", 0.9);
              
              c.append("svg:title")
              .text(function(j) {
                return Math.max(j.value, 0);
              });
              

            series++;
          });

          //Tooltip
          tooltip = g.append('text')
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
            .style('font-size', textSizeTooltip);
        }
      };

      // Options for the Radar chart, other than default
      var myOptions = {
        w: w,
        h: h,
        ExtraWidthX: 180,
        labelScale: 0.7,
        levels: 5,
        levelScale: 0.85,
        facetPaddingScale: 1.9,
        maxValue: 0.6,
        showAxes: true,
        showAxesLabels: true,
        showLegend: true,
        showLevels: true,
        showLevelsLabels: false,
        showPolygons: true,
        showVertices: true
      };

      RadarChart.draw(divId, json, myOptions);

      ////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////////// Initiate legend ////////////////
      ////////////////////////////////////////////

      var svg = d3.select('#chart-radar')
        .selectAll('svg')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", w + 300)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style("font-size", textSizeLegend);

      // Initiate Legend
      var legend = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(90,20)');

      // Create colour squares
      legend.selectAll('rect')
        .data(legendOptions)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", w - 8)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * 20;
        })
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return colorscale(i);
        });

      // Create text next to squares
      legend.selectAll('text')
        .data(legendOptions)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", w + 3)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * 20 + 9;
        })
        .attr("font-size", textSizeLegend)
        .attr("fill", "#737373")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });
    };

    function update() {
      console.log("here");
      json = [
        [{
          "axis": "A",
          "value": 4
        }, {
          "axis": "B",
          "value": 13
        }, {
          "axis": "C",
          "value": 8
        }, {
          "axis": "D",
          "value": 15
        }, {
          "axis": "E",
          "value": 2
        }, {
          "axis": "F",
          "value": 5
        }, {
          "axis": "G",
          "value": 9
        }, {
          "axis": "H",
          "value": 3
        }, {
          "axis": "I",
          "value": 1
        }]
      ];
      drawRadarChart('#chart-radar', wMaior, wMaior);
    };

    drawRadarCharts();

    d3.select("button").on("click", update);
  </script>

</html>
```

**Why is this a hack?**

You haven't followed the enter, update, exit paradigm.  You are destroying the chart and rebuilding it on each update.  This is wasteful as much of it stays the same.  It's a hack because I'm storing the polygon points before destruction just for the transition.  We should be operating on the same polygon...

Comment: Hi mark, I know this is probably a longshot! But I was hoping you could provide an insight why it wouldn't work with more than one data entry? ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8g8s6Lz/3/)). I've tried to debug, and the only thing I've found is when there is just one set of data to be drawn on, the length of the array is 13, but when there is two, the first set of points array is 7, and the second 19. When I guess it should be 13/13? I'm not sure If I have any idea what I'm on about. Hopefully I can figure it out myself, I don't think it would be appropriate to ask  it in another question!

Comment: @Iolio, There's lot of things amiss in your code.  First, the biggest is variable scoping issues.  You are relying on global variables which are tripping you up.  For instance, in your update, you create a **local** variable named `json` then call your redraw function.  Since this reassignment is local, it doesn't affect the global `json` variable.   You should be passing this variable into your draw....

Comment: @Iolio, second, you are doing a lot of explicit looping on your data and `d3` is all about binding with no explicit loops.  This causes you trouble particularly in your `.append("svg:circle")` stuff where your re-push to datavalues (this is why you get 19 in one array)...

Comment: @Iolio, third, you haven't modified the transition stuff I wrote to take into account multiple polygons.

Comment: @lolio, here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8g8s6Lz/4/) where I've started to address the above issues.  It's a little too much code for me to take the time to wade into it deeper.  I wish I had the time to re-write it, but I've got a real day-job to do :)

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of code! Thank you very much for providing a quick fix/workaround for the current situation though! I may take a stab at a rewrite soon, I'm sure it would be a great learning experience for me. Thanks again, you've been a massive help :)